# How to set alpha TextView at RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

how to set alpha at RelativeLayout like this image?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it both in xml and programatically by using 8-digit color(#AARRGGBB) like this:

```
android:background="#CC000000"
```

first two digit is for transparency. for more details look at [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)

or you can do it programatically in this way:

```
View yourRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.yourrelativelayout);
Drawable background = yourRelativeLayout.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(85);
```